# Gearman PHP job not submitted to server if workers running

Tags: php, mysql, gearman

I installed gearman v1.1.18-27-ga778fee on my machine and also installed the php-pecl extension. I am able to submit the job to server and they are persisted to a mysql table. When no worker is running, the job gets persisted to mysql. When I start the worker, the job is processed and then cleared from the table. The issue I have is, when the worker is running in the background, and then I submit a job to the server, the job is not persisted to the table, neither is it being processed by the worker. Is this an issue with php extension, or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not familiar with php, but I'm pretty sure it's an issue either of implementation or of php extension. Is [it](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gearman/RBLlognhnes) a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for a few hours, I found that the issue was not in Gearman but with my code where the data I was submitting to gearman was not yet committed by a previous transaction and so gearman worker could not find the required rows in table.